# Redirect to subroutine, not file or external command

Tags: perl, filehandle

I know I can open  a filehandle and redirect it to a file like so:

```
open(HANDLE, ">", "filename.txt");
```

I can also redirect it to a command like the following:

```
open(HANDLE, "|-", "grep hello");
```

What I'd like to do is direct it to a function:

```
open(HANDLE, "|func", f);
```

Where `f` is a function which takes one argument, a filehandle, and then can read from that filehandle as it sees fit, and write however it wants to.

I know I can emulate this by creating a new file with `f(FILEHANDLE)` in it, but that has some issues, for example, if `f(FILEHANDLE)`s behaviour sometimes changes, instead of making a function `g(option1, option2)` which takes parameters and returns the function `f(FILEHANDLE)`, in the separate file case, we'd need to pass command line parameters, with all the issues of command line quoting etc.

Any way (or any library) that allows me to direct a filehandle to a subroutine? I don't mind if the library behind the scenes does a `fork()`, I just want to avoid the messiness of piping the data to a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want code to have the interface of a variable, you want to `tie` code to the variable. See [Tie::Handle](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aHandle).

Comment: I'm not sure how these achieves what I'm asking, which is how to open a filehandle to a function. I don't want the interface of a variable.

Comment: `HANDLE` is a variable. you want a function to be called on a `print` to that handle instead of the normal operation of that variable. It achieves exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I think you've answered my question, but it doesn't seem to handle output from `system()` calls. I've put another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890045/pipe-filehandle-to-fork-of-self