# Pipe filehandle to fork of self

Tags: perl

I know I can do the following:

```
open(STDOUT, "|-", "cmd");
```

Which presumably results in the following:

1. `fork();`
2. `exec("cmd");`
3. Link STDOUT of original process to STDIN of new process.

What I'd like to do is step 2 above, i.e. don't do the `exec()`. Just have two copies of the current process continuing, the STDIN of the child linked to the STDOUT of the parent.

Which would then allow me to continue on like this:

```
if (! $pid)
{
  # Handle data in child here
  open OUTFILE1 $file1;
  open OUTFILE2 $file2;
  my $i = 0;
  while (<>)
  {
    print (i % 2 ? OUTFILE1 : OUTFILE2) "Line $i: $_";
    ++$i;
  }
  exit;
}
else
{
  # Continue parent here
  print STDOUT "Hello World from print()";
  system("echo Hello World from system()");
}
```

The above code should add a line number to the output and write this data alternatively line by line to different files (I know it's a bit silly, but it's just an example).

Is there a way or a library that does this? I considered `perltie` but it didn't seem to handle results from `system()`, hence I believe I need a separate process to actually pipe STDOUT to.

Comment: I've edited the question which hopefully makes it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, you simply want

```
open(STDOUT, "|-", "-");
```

but `open3` also only takes one line, has better error reporting, and would allow you to capture STDERR as well.

```
use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );
use POSIX      qw( _exit );

sub child {
   print("Hello World from print()\n");
   system("echo", "Hello World from system()");
}

my $pid = open3(
   '<&STDIN',
   \local *CHILD_STDOUT,
   '>&STDERR',
   '-',
);

if (!$pid) {
   if (eval { child(); 1 }) {
      _exit(0);
   } else {
      print(STDERR $@);
      _exit($! || ($? >> 8) || 255);
   }
}

while (<CHILD_STDOUT>) {
   ...
}

waitpid($pid, 0);
```

Comment: Exactly what I want. Didn't think of the `open` without the command argument.